# How can I change option empty_value of choice field type in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

```
{{ 
    form_row(form.quantity, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'center-text', 
            style: "color: red;"
        }, 
        'empty_value': '1'
    }) 
}}
```

I change the value of empty_value but it could not effect.

thanks.

Comment: What you mean when saying "change option empty_value of choice"?

Comment: I mean that I defined 'empty_data' in xxxType.php and I'd like to change value of 'empty_data' in xxx.html.twig. Is it possible?

Comment: "empty_data" is set on form class or form building.

Comment: "empty_data" is set on form class.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `empty_value` with `value` like this :

```
{{ 
    form_row(form.quantity, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'center-text', 
            style: "color: red;"
        }, 
        'value': '1'
    }) 
}}
```

Comment: Why are you saying that ? Does my post not providing an answer ? Of course it does ! According to me, this is the problem in his code.